# Methods to compute slope of curve tending to a horizontal asymptote

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

This is a follow-up question to ones I asked some time ago:

[Performing a linear regression on a subset of data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321915/performing-a-linear-regression-on-a-subset-of-data); and,

[Slope interpretation in simple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331690/slope-interpretation-in-simple-linear-regression).

I have a number of data points, that, when plotted, form a smooth monotonically-increasing curve tending to a horizontal asymptote. That is the slope is decelerating towards zero.

I am interested in whether there is statistical evidence that the slope of the curve based on the terminal data points is zero vs. the case when the slope is greater than zero. That is, testing

$H_{0}: \beta_{1}$ = 0 vs. $H_{1}: \beta_{1}$ > 0

I estimate the curve slope via a linear model in R using lm() with an intercept term.

I have two options which have been suggested to me, but I am having trouble justifying one over the other:

(1) compute curve slope using a fixed *number* of terminal data points (e.g., 10); or

(2) compute curve slope based on a fixed *proportion* of data points (e.g., 10%).

Since at least 2 data points are needed to calculate slope, choosing the 2nd option with $n$ = 2 where 10% of the data is used in the computation makes little sense (as 2*0.10 = 0.2 data points). Thus, the choice between options (1) and (2) is dependent on the amount of data at hand.

Typically, all available data is employed in calculating slope.

**My question is**: can the choice between the two options be further justified, as not simply "cherry-picking"?

In my case, the goal is to ensure that the null hypothesis is NOT rejected, which is counter to the norm of rejecting the null.

---

In order to clarify my question, the data I have is as follows:

```
   specs  means
1      1 1.0000
2      2 1.6750
3      3 2.1142
4      4 2.4214
5      5 2.6050
6      6 2.7391
7      7 2.8276
8      8 2.8780
9      9 2.9217
10    10 2.9490
11    11 2.9638
12    12 2.9769
13    13 2.9833
14    14 2.9887
15    15 2.9925
16    16 2.9929
17    17 2.9955
18    18 2.9967
19    19 2.9985
20    20 2.9981
```

which produces the following curve:

[image]

The above plot depicts an accumulation curve of the number of samples collected (**specs**) versus the mean number of species found (**means**). Thus, we can expect to find approximately 3 species on average through the random sampling of 100 individuals.

The computed slope estimate based on conducting a simple linear regression on the last 10  points (50% of terminal data points) occurring on the curve is 0.0033194 (one-sided p-value = 0.000175). This result is strong indication that further sampling of this species should not be ceased, as the null hypothesis of zero-slope cannot be rejected.

Comment: Could you please explain what $\beta_1$ represents in your model?  You must have something more complex than "a linear model in R using `lm`", for otherwise $\beta_1$ would be the slope estimate, pure and simple, and the concept of "curve slope" would seem to be irrelevant.  For this question to be answerable I think you will need to present us a specific regression model or at least explain your objectives with enough precision to enable us to infer the model you have in mind.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @whuber I have added some further details (data and graph with short explanation). Hopefully things are clearer now.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Please see the updated post for additional information.

Comment: A third option is to fit the data to an asymptotic exponential equation and inspect the asymptote value. Here I have fit your data to the equation "y = a * (1.0 - exp(bx))" with resulting values a =  2.9983984133696504E+00 and b = -4.0808350554404227E-01, and the  95% confidence intervals for the asymptote "a" are [2.99645E+00, 3.00034E+00], and your maximum means value from the data is 2.9981 which is within these bounds. My interpretation of this is that you would not improve the fitted estimate for the asymptote by acquiring additional data at the high end of the data range.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Interesting... although one can argue that there are in fact multiple parametric asymptotic models that can be used to fit the data. Another model could be the 2-parameter model y = (a * x) / (b + x). I just wanted verification that my existing 2 options are actually sensible. Thanks.

Comment: Point taken - from my perspective, if the fitted equation has a single value for asymptote, with parameter confidence intervals, and a good fit to the data then you're done.